# Impossible to get data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

1. I created the json data as text with javascript
2. I stringify it in order to safely transfer it to another file
3. I send it by post to a php file
4. I get the post.
5. I decode it.
6. I checked the result with JSON formatter and it says everything ok.
7. I try to get the data and it always return an empty value. No error.

Now I show you everything:
**Step 1**

```
var team = '[';
var filas=$("#players").find("tbody").find("tr").not(".hidden");
for(i=0;i<$(filas).length;i++)
{
    team+='{"type_player": "' + $(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(0).html() + '" ,"mo": ' + parseInt($(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(1).html()) + ', "st": ' + parseInt($(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(2).html()) + ', "de": ' + parseInt($(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(3).html()) + ', "ar": ' + parseInt($(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(4).html()) + ', "N": "' + $(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(6).html() + '" , "D": "' + $(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(7).html() + '" , "price": ' + parseInt($(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(8).html()) + ', "habs": ' + $(filas).eq(i).find("input.p_habs").val() + ', "max_number": '+ $(filas).eq(i).find("td.dato").eq(9).html() + ' }';
    if((i+1)<$(filas).length)
    {
        team+=", ";
    }
}
team+="]";
```

**Step 2**

```
$("#lista_Players").val(JSON.stringify(team));
```

Where lista_Players is a hidden input within a Form

**Step 3**

```
<form action='crear_raza.php' method="post">
```

**Step 4**

```
$play=$_POST['players'];
```

**Step 5**

```
$players=json_decode($play, true);
```

**Step 6**

I print_r($players) showing:

```
[{"type_player": "Putrefactos" ,"mo": 5, "st": 3, "de": 3, "ar": 8, "N": "GM" , "D": "AFP" , "price": 40000, "habs": [22,60], "max_number": 16 }, {"type_player": "Pestigors" ,"mo": 6, "st": 3, "de": 3, "ar": 8, "N": "FGM" , "D": "AP" , "price": 80000, "habs": [20,60,64], "max_number": 4 }, {"type_player": "Guerreros de Nurgle" ,"mo": 4, "st": 4, "de": 2, "ar": 9, "N": "FGM" , "D": "AP" , "price": 110000, "habs": [5,57,60,64], "max_number": 4 }, {"type_player": "Bestia de Nurgle" ,"mo": 4, "st": 5, "de": 1, "ar": 9, "N": "F" , "D": "AGMP" , "price": 140000, "habs": [5,34,57,60,62,64,71,72], "max_number": 1 }, {"type_player": "erger" ,"mo": 3, "st": 3, "de": 3, "ar": 3, "N": "A" , "D": "P" , "price": 2345324, "habs": [1], "max_number": 4 }]
```

*JSON formatter* exactly says: VALID JSON (RFC 4627)

**Step 7**

```
echo $players[0]["mo"];
```

It returns me: [

```
echo $players[0]["type_player"];
```

It returns me nothing

Any idea????

Comment: First idea which comes to mind: why would someone generate JSON by string concatenation, when JS supports it natively very well.

Comment: Yeldar, I've never taken computer classes and my idea of building a JSON with javascript is quite innocent. Might you illustrate me with an example? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should know that JSON means **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation and building string is pointless. You can create simple object and put your variables to it. 
For example:

```
var players = [
   {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
   {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
   {"firstName":"Peter","lastName": "Jones"}
];
```

Comment: And when you get data from elements, how can you built a job object?